# Module not found error when importing component in React app [Solved]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

> Where was the problem?

In IntelliJ

> How to solve it?

Go to

*Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript*

Disable

*Typescript Language Service*

---

Problem Description:
I am working on a React app, and I'm encountering a "Module not found" error when trying to import a component in my App.tsx file. I have checked the file and folder structure, verified the import statement, and ensured that the files exist in the correct locations. However, the error persists, and I'm not sure what else could be causing it.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new React app using Create React App or a similar setup.
2. Set up an App.tsx file as the entry point for your app.
3. Create a RegisterPage.tsx component in the src directory.
4. Attempt to import the RegisterPage component in App.tsx.

Expected Result:
The RegisterPage component should be imported successfully, and the app should render without any errors.

Actual Result:
The app throws a "Module not found" error with the message: "Error: Can't resolve './RegisterPage' in 'C:\etc\Desktop\BeerSite\beersite\src'".

Code Snippets:

`App.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RegisterPage from './RegisterPage';

function App() {
  // ... (rest of the code)
}
```

`RegisterPage.tsx`:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';
import Register from './Components/RegisterComponent';

const RegisterPage: FC = () => {
  // ... (rest of the code)
};


export default RegisterPage;
```

File structure (I know it's better to use a /Page folder but for simplicity I put them in the same one):

```
|- src
     |- App.tsx
     |- RegisterPage.tsx
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

1. Double-checked the file and folder structure to ensure the correct
   path for import.
2. Verified that the file names and extensions match the import
   statement.
3. Restarted the development server to check for changes.

Environment Details:

- OS: Windows 11
- Node.js version: v18.17.0
- NPM version: 9.6.7
- React version: 18.2.0

Additional Notes:
InteliJ 2022 IDE Ultimate

Comment: Does it work if you add `.tsx` to the end of that import statement?

Comment: Yes, . The IDE gives an error, but the webpage runs perfectly. Thank you so much Andy.

Comment: You may want to check your TS config. I think there's a way for you to do it your original way with the [`moduleResolution` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution) enabled to the correct type. The IDE may be just a lint warning. See what happens if you change the config.

Comment: Answers should be answers, not part of the question, and questions should not be tagged "solved" in their title, rather by accepting an answer. FWIW it's rare the TS service would need to be globally disabled; I'd look at project specific configs both in the project and the IDE.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?